# ios - printing HTML from a .html file not working in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview

I got "hello world" text to print after I hardcoded some html right into my UIWebView functions, but now I am trying to move that HTML to a file elsewhere on the file system, and it isnt rendering.

Here is what I have:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{   
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"learn" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"src/html_files"];

    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [theWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}
```

and my HTML file is in a directory that I made called src/html_files and the file is named learn.html

What am I doing incorrectly that the HTML is not rendering on the screen?

Thank you!

Comment: **Where** on the filesystem is this file?  Is this a bundle resource, built with your app?  Is it a file in your app's **Documents**, or **Caches** directory?  Please debug your app.  Stop after `htmlFile` is assigned.  Use `NSLog()` to show the value of `htmlFile`.  Then, step past the line where `htmlString` is assigned.  What is the value of `htmlString`?  Is it `nil`?  I would always recommend using the `NSError` parameter of methods that take it, and checking it after the operation completes.  You are passing `error:nil`, which doesn't allow you to see errors if they occur.

Comment: @Nate I made a new "group" and put the html file there. I am not sure it means it is in a bundle resource. How do I add it there? Or should I add it there? What was the correct thing for me to have done with that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so **Groups** are just a construct in Xcode for keeping your app's resources organized.  Although Xcode uses the little folder icon, it doesn't necessarily mean those are actually separate folders on the (Mac or iOS) filesystem.

But, it sounds like you have added that file as a *bundle resource*.  That's what the code you posted looks like, too, but I had to ask, to be sure.

Most likely, the only thing wrong is that this:

```objc
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"learn" 
                                                     ofType:@"html" 
                                                inDirectory:@"src/html_files"];
```

should be this instead:

```objc
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"learn" 
                                                     ofType:@"html"];
```

From [the Apple documentation for NSBundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html),

```objc
+ (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name 
                       ofType:(NSString *)extension 
                  inDirectory:(NSString *)bundlePath
```

> *bundlePath*
>
> The path of a top-level bundle directory. This must be a valid path. For example, to 
>   specify the bundle directory for a Mac app, you might specify the path /Applications/MyApp.app.

The `bundlePath` parameter is not meant to specify relative paths to your bundle resources.  The version of `pathForResource:ofType:` that does not have a `bundlePath` parameter is almost always what you'll use.  It will find the **learn.html** file wherever it lives, once your app is installed, and return the full path to that.  You don't really have to worry about how it's nested.  It's just a bundle resource.

Give that a try.  As I suggested in my comment, though, I always recommend taking advantage of the `error` parameter for debugging:

```objc
NSError* error;
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error];
if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error with stringWithContentsOfFile: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```